# Apache httpd.conf Only use SSL for subdomain and give 404 for other https URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, https, httpd.conf

I have a current configuration for my website mail client:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:443

    <VirtualHost *:443>
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
            <Directory /var/www/mailclient>
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>
            DocumentRoot /var/www/mailclient
            ServerName mail.*
            ServerAlias mail.*
    </VirtualHost>
```

When i try to reach https:// mail.domain1.com or https:// mail.domain2.com this works fine.

But when i try to reach https:// domain1.com or https:// sub.domain1.com i still see the web mail client, but i dont want to see anything but a 404 or something like that. So how can i restrict this virtualHost only for a specific sub domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a default vhost that will kick back an error.  It needs to be above your current vhost in order to be default, but below the `NameVirtualHost` configuration.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName default.filler.name
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
    <Location />
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
    <Directory /var/www/mailclient>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mailclient
    ServerName mail.*
    ServerAlias mail.*
</VirtualHost>
```

It'll 403 instead of 404.  Close enough?

Answer (score 2):

Apache will serve the default (*) vhost when it can't find the right one.
You could use a [default vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default) to get around this.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) http://mymainwebsite.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

This will prevent it from popping up if someone connects to port 443 with the IP or another subdomain.

Comment: When i put this code above my current VirtualHost i get an ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error which might indicate a loop. Im not sure what is going wrong?